# Ajax template function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url('profile/update_user_password'); ?>",
                cache: false,
                data: $('#form_changepassword').serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#btn_updatepassword').addClass('disabled');
                    $('#btn_updatepassword').attr('disabled', true);
                    $('#btn_updatepassword').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fast-spin'></i>");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#btn_updatepassword').removeClass('disabled');
                    $('#btn_updatepassword').attr('disabled', false);
                    $('#btn_updatepassword').html(' <?php echo lang('update_password_button_text') ?>');
                },
                success: function (response) {

                }
            });
```

This above is a function of ajax. 
I want to make a function that take beforesend as a parameter 
like below

```
function myAjax(ajax_url, ajaxcallback , dataType = "json" , cache = false , reqtype = "POST" , data = "" , errorId = "" ) {
    type: reqtype,
    url: ajax_url,
    cache: cache,
    data : data,
    dataType: dataType,
    success:ajaxcallback ,
```

}

I want to call this function with before function as a parameter in function

```
myAjax("url " , clouse_fun_for_success, "" , false , "POST" , data , "#error" )
```

How can I set some setting before call this AJAX template function because every time login in before function would be change

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this:

`var beforeSend = function() {
                    $('#btn_updatepassword').addClass('disabled');
                    $('#btn_updatepassword').attr('disabled', true);
                    $('#btn_updatepassword').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fast-spin'></i>");
};`

`function myAjax(ajax_url, ajaxcallback ,`*beforeSend*`, dataType = "json" , cache = false , reqtype = "POST" , data = "" , errorId = "" ) {
    type: reqtype,
    url: ajax_url,
    cache: cache,
    data : data,
    beforeSend:`*beforeSend*`,
    dataType: dataType,
    success:ajaxcallback ,
    ...`